# Conversion from RSS to RDF

Tags: rss, rdf

I don't quite understand RDF, but I am looking to convert RSS feeds from places like yahoo and google into RDF format to display on a website.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Update: it seems I need to understand XSTL and stuff like that.

Comment: If you want to display it on a website, you want HTML, not RDF. RDF is just a generic way to store data tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/) implements both RSS and RDF.  It's open source.

Comment: I dont think that tells me how to convert from RSS to RDF

Comment: The source code might though.  From a quick look it appears like they're both XML formats so at least that's common.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the RSS variants are RDF compatible :

http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/02/04/incompatible-rss

So one solution could be to convert the other RSS variants via XSL-T to an RDF compatible version (e.g. 1.0).